# 1C и мобильное приложение

Tags: swift, 1с, мобильная-разработка

Как связать мобильное приложение, написанное не в мобильной платформе 1С, а скажем на том же свифте, с базой данных 1С? Причем, чтобы данные отбирались из базы выборочно. Каков механизм данной работы?

Comment: А база данных удаленная или вы планируете хранить базу данных 1С локально?

Comment: удаленная. но протестить собираюсь локально. как происходит взаимодействие другой среды разработки и базы 1С?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю оптимальный вариант для Вас это использовать веб сервисы 1с, из мобильного приложения обращаться к сервису, который отдаст то что нужно.

1.В дереве конфигурации Общие - Web-сервисы- добавить

2.На вкладке Операции добавить поля для отбора данных которые будет принимать сервис

3.Перейти Действия - открыть модуль.

4.В коде описать модуль который будет принимать входящие данные, обрабатывать их и отдавать ответ, например

```
 Функция Request(АргументИзПункта2)
     // получим типы из XDTO
    ТипXDTOРезультатОперации = ФабрикаXDTO.Тип("RequestLK", "РезультатОперации");
    ТипXDTOСвойства = ФабрикаXDTO.Тип("RequestLK", "Свойства");
    XDTOСвойства = ФабрикаXDTO.Создать(ТипXDTOСвойства);
    Запрос = новый Запрос;
    Запрос.Текст = "Выбрать * из Справочник.номенклатура где 
    Номенклатура.наименование = &АргументОтбораИзПункта2"
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("АргументИзПункта2",АргументОтбораИзПункта2);
    РезультатЗапроса = ЗапросСтрок.Выполнить();
    Выборка = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();
    Пока Выборка.Следующий() Цикл
    XDTOПозиции = ФабрикаXDTO.Создать(ТипXDTOРезультатОперации);
    XDTOПозиции.Name = Выборка.Наименование;
    XDTOСвойства.items.Добавить(XDTOПозиции);
    КонецЦикла;
    Возврат XDTOСвойства;
 КонецФункции
```

[Официальная документация 1С по веб сервисам](http://v8.1c.ru/overview/Term_000000273.htm)

Comment: @Dmitry поправил и дополнил ответ)